# Split list after repeating elements

Tags: python, list

I have this loop for creating a list of coefficients:

```
for i in N:
    p = 0
    for k in range(i+1):
        p += (x**k)/factorial(k)
        c.append(p)
```

For example `N = [2, 3, 4]` would give list c:

```
[1.0, 2.0, 2.5, 1.0, 2.0, 2.5, 2.6666666666666665, 1.0, 2.0, 2.5, 2.6666666666666665, 2.708333333333333]
```

I want a way of making separate lists after each 1.0 element. For example a nested list:

```
[[1.0, 2.0, 2.5], [1.0, 2.0, 2.5, 2.6666666666666665], [1.0, 2.0, 2.5, 2.6666666666666665, 2.708333333333333]]
```

I was thinking of using an if test, like

```
for c_ in c:
    if c_ == 1.0:
        anotherList.append(c_)
```

This only appends 1.0's though and I don't know how I can make it append everything after a one instead of just 1.0.

Comment: `itertools` is the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

you can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) in list comprehension :

```
>>> [[1.0]+list(g) for k,g in itertools.groupby(l,lambda x:x==1.0) if not k]
[[1.0, 2.0, 2.5], [1.0, 2.0, 2.5, 2.6666666666666665], [1.0, 2.0, 2.5, 2.6666666666666665, 2.708333333333333]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Try something like

```
another_list = []
for c_ in c:
    if c_ == 1.0:
        another_list.append([])
    another_list[-1].append(c_)
```

Thanks for the suggestion @James Jenkinson

Comment: You could just use `another_list[-1].append(_c)` to always be referring to the most recent list, thus saving a precious two lines of code.